# How to mock not installed npm package in jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

How to mock not installed npm package in [jest](https://jestjs.io)?

I'm writing a library and I need to test some cases when optional dependencies are not installed.

**Update**

My library has an optional dependency. The end-user of my library can optionally to install `styled-components`.

In my tests (jest) I covered the case when `styled-components` is installed.
Now I need to cover the case when the package is not installed.

```js
test(`When styled-components is not installed`, () => {
  process.env.SC_NOT_INSTALLED = true
  const fn = () => {
    const styled = require(`./styled`)
  }
  expect(fn).toThrow(Error)
})
```

```js
let styled

try {
  require.resolve(`styled-components`)
  styled = require(`styled-components`)

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === `test` && process.env.SC_NOT_INSTALLED) {
    throw new Error(`Imitation styled-components is not installed`)
  }
}
catch {
  styled = () => {
    throw new Error(`Module not found: styled-components`)
  }
}

export default styled
```

`process.env.SC_NOT_INSTALLED` -> will not work because as I guess the test are running in different process.

Comment: Are you asking how to mock a library that isn't installed, or asking how to mock a library that *is* installed to look like it isn't.  Please update your question with code and your test to give us something we can use to respond.

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an exception is thrown in your `try` you are exporting a *function*.

Calling the exported *function* is what throws the `Error`.

Change your test to this:

```js
test(`When styled-components is not installed`, () => {
  process.env.SC_NOT_INSTALLED = true;
  const styled = require(`./styled`).default;
  expect(() => styled()).toThrow('Module not found: styled-components');  // Success!
});
```

...and it should work.

---

**Update**

If you are calling `require('./styled')` multiple times in the same test file, then you will want to add an `afterEach` that calls [`jest.resetModules`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestresetmodules), otherwise `Jest` will cache the module and just keep returning the same module for each `require`:

```js
afterEach(() => {
  jest.resetModules();
})

test(`When styled-components is installed`, () => {
  const styled = require(`./styled`).default;
  // ...
});

test(`When styled-components is not installed`, () => {
  process.env.SC_NOT_INSTALLED = true;
  const styled = require(`./styled`).default;
  expect(() => styled()).toThrow('Module not found: styled-components');  // Success!
});
```

Comment: No it is not that I meant. I need to check both sections of `try` and `catch`. 
Your snippet leads only first `try` section always. I want to test the `catch`.

Comment: The test in my answer tests the catch from the code in the question @sultan

Comment: When an error is thrown in the `try` it drops into the `catch` and that returns a *function that throws an error when it is called*. So the test above causes the `catch` to run, then verifies that the function returned by the `catch` throws an error when it is called.  Let me know if that makes sense and if you have any questions @sultan

Comment: Thank you for helping to find solution @brian-lives-outdoors. Your given code is wrong. When you call const styled = require(`./styled`) you never rise error in catch section. First of all the env.variable not effecting other process. So the requires will be always success.

Comment: Setting the `process.env` variable is guaranteed to work since the module gets `required` by the test code within the same `process` (even when `Jest` is spawning multiple child processes), so that part is working.  I did notice that I wasn't getting `styled` using the `default` export, so I've updated that above.  I also updated the test to [specifically test for the error](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tothrowerror) thrown in the `catch` to demonstrate that it is working properly. @sultan

Comment: Ahhh...I think I know why it hasn't been working for you.  I bet you have a test for when it **is** installed earlier in the same test file and `Jest` is caching the module and returning the same one for when it **isn't** installed.  I've updated my answer above with how to fix that.  @sultan