# Mocking federated modules in host application for jest

Tags: unit-testing, webpack, jestjs, mocking, webpack-module-federation

Question is exactly same here in fact but has different context:
[How to mock not installed npm package in jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55411559/how-to-mock-not-installed-npm-package-in-jest)

I am part of a project where new Module Federation is used from webpack. Basically, I have a host app and it uses remote apps. I am doing the same thing here for the routing:
https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/tree/master/shared-routes2

My host app importing the remote apps' route as similar
(I took this example from module-federation repo: https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/blob/master/shared-routes2/app1/src/App.js)

```js
// app1/src/App.js

import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";


import localRoutes from "./routes";
import remoteRoutes from "app2/routes";

const routes = [...localRoutes, ...remoteRoutes];

const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div data-test-id="App-navigation">
      <h1>App 1</h1>
      <React.Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <Switch>
          {routes.map((route) => (
            <Route
              key={route.path}
              path={route.path}
              component={route.component}
              exact={route.exact}
            />
          ))}
        </Switch>
      </React.Suspense>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

and my test file for this component look like this:

```js
// app1/src/App.test.js

import React from 'react';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

import App from './App';

jest.mock('app2/routes');

describe('App', () => {
  test('should render navigation', async () => {
    const { findByTestId } = render(
      <MemoryRouter>
        <App />
      </MemoryRouter>,
    );
    const app = await findByTestId('App-navigation');

    expect(drawerMenu).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

this test produce the error as is:

```bash
❯ yarn test App.test.js
yarn run v1.22.10
$ jest App.test.js
 FAIL  src/App.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'app2/routes' from 'src/App.test.js'

       6 | import App from './App';
       7 |
    >  8 | jest.mock('app2/routes');
         |      ^
       9 |

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:306:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.test.js:8:6)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.78 s
Ran all test suites matching /App.test.js/i.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I believe this error occurs because there is actually no module named `app2/routes`. It's a federated module produced by webpack module federation plugin. However, `jest` looks for the actual module before mocks it.

This is the part I am stuck and out of ideas.

Comment: for a general strategy. I created `remote-apps` folder on inside my `tests` folder and put the mocks in it and structured it with folders by name of remote-apps: `tests > remote-apps > remote-app-A.js` and I put these mock folders inside my `jest.config.js` as `setupFilesAfterEnv`  as follows `setupFilesAfterEnv: [  '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect',  './tests/remote-apps/remote-app-A.js']`

Comment: I just implemented what you suggested but it still throws the same error. Could you help what did you do to resolve it in detail ? You can help me for this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72909100/how-to-test-one-micro-front-end-component-in-which-other-micro-frontend-componen

Comment: For future visitors, @micronyks found his own solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72936395/5018572

Long story short. put your `jest.mock` expressions top of your file, below your `import`s

Answer (score 2):

Jest offer virtual mocking and it solves the issue. (I found the solution out of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56052635/5018572)

```
jest.mock('app2/routes', 
  () => { 
    // some mocking for my remote app routes
  },
  { virtual: true }
);
```

after you make the mocking factory, you simply pass `{ virtual: true }` options and jest stop complaining about the module's existence.

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/66387224/2) to the question [Mocking federated modules in host application for jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66387224/mocking-federated-modules-in-host-application-for-jest) by the OP [Halil Kayer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5018572/halil-kayer) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>