# how to test one micro front end component in which other micro frontend component is being used using jest and enzyme

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme, ts-jest, micro-frontend

I have two micro frontends (written in **react** & **typescript**). **dashboard MFE** and **Common MFE**

common MFE has several component which can be consumed by dashboard independently. eg. Notification component, loader component etc...

MFE1 has **dashboard.component.tsx** and simplified version looks below,

```
  import React from react
  ....
  ....
  import notificationComponent from 'common/NotificationComponent'  <<====This is external module or component

  // and several other component which are part of common micro frontend

  const DashboardComponent = () => {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    return (<div>
           <notificationComponent .../>
           ....
   </div>)
  }

export default DashboardComponent;
```

I defined its type in remoteTypes.d.ts file as below,

**src/remoteTypes.d.ts**

```
declare module 'common/NotificatioComponent' {
    const NotificatioComponent: React.ComponentType<{ notification: { title: string, description: string, color: string } }>;
    export default NotificatioComponent;
}
```

This is working fine.

***The problem is in unit testing of dashboard component with jest and enzyme***.

when I write and run a simple test,

```
test('dashboard component',()=>{
   const wrapper =  mount(
            <Provider store={myStore}>
              <Router>
                <DashboardComponent />
              </Router>
            </Provider> 
   )
})
```

it throws error as below,

> can not find module 'common/NotificationComponent' from
> 'src/components/dashboard.component.tsx'
>
> Require Stack:
> 'src/components/dashboard.component.tsx
> 'src/components/dashboard.component.text.tsx

How should I resolve this error?

---

I'm exporting notification component as follow,

webpackage.config.js

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = require('webpack').container;
const path = require('path');
const deps = require('./package.json').dependencies;
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  ...
  ....
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({

      name: 'common',

      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',

      exposes: {
        // expose each component
        './CommonBootstrap':'./src/bootstrap',
        './NotificationComponent': './src/components/notification/components/notification.component',   <<===== from here
      },

      shared: {
      ....
      }
  ],
};
```

---

**Update**

I found a good reference : [Mocking federated modules in host application for jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66387224/mocking-federated-modules-in-host-application-for-jest)

and tried in similar way but I get the same error still.

```
test('dashboard component',()=>{



       jest.mock('common/NotificationComponent', 
         () => { 
    
          ,
         { virtual: true }
       );

       const wrapper =  mount(
                <Provider store={myStore}>
                  <Router>
                    <DashboardComponent />
                  </Router>
                </Provider> 
       )
    })
```

but same error. what is wrong ?

Comment: I found some reference but couldn't fig out the right approach : https://single-spa.js.org/docs/testing/units/#jest-config

Comment: I found some close answers but I still get the same error : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66387224/mocking-federated-modules-in-host-application-for-jest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay. Finally I found the answer.

In above code snippet, I was doing one thing wrong as discussed below,

In earlier try, it was still failing because I was using `jest.mock(...)` inside `it(...)` or `test(...)` block as shown below,

```
test('dashboard component',()=>{

   jest.mock('common/NotificationComponent', 
     () => { 
         myFunc: () => 'hello'
      ,
     { virtual: true }
   );

   const wrapper =  mount(
            <Provider store={myStore}>
              <Router>
                <DashboardComponent />
              </Router>
            </Provider> 
   )
})
```

**Solution**,

This below code,

```
 jest.mock('common/NotificationComponent', 
         () => { 
             myFunc: () => 'hello'
          ,
         { virtual: true }
       );
```

you should put **at top of your file**. Don't put it inside `it(...)` or `test(...)` block. So it will look like below,

```
 import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
 import { shallow, mount } from "enzyme";

 jest.mock('common/NotificationComponent', 
     () => { 
         myFunc: () => 'hello'
      ,
     { virtual: true }
 );


test('dashboard component',()=>{

   const wrapper =  mount(
            <Provider store={myStore}>
              <Router>
                <DashboardComponent />
              </Router>
            </Provider> 
   )
})
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention in my answer what neet to be put outside.

Comment: Hey I am glad you figured your solution :)